# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource. AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, http, cors

I hope you can me solve this issue of mine, because I'm getting this error when I'm executing the code below using created on angularJs.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/user. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

```
400 Bad Request
capi-eval.signnow.com 37 B 54.146.69.118:443 1.11s
HeadersResponseCache
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Connection  
close
Content-Type application/json

view source
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-He...    
authorization
Access-Control-Request-Me...    
GET
Cache-Control   
max-age=0
Connection  
keep-alive
Host    
capi-eval.signnow.com
Origin  
http://localhost
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
```

followed the instructions from different references and added additional Headers but but still didn't work. Hope someone can guide me on how to get this resolve.

When I'm using RestClient firefox plugin I can get the json response with problems.

```
app.controller('testController',function(cudaSignApi) {
    cudaSignApi();
});


app.factory('cudaSignApi', function ($http,$q){
  return function() {
      $http.get('https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/user',{
          headers: {
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
          },
      })
      .then(function(resultJson) {
        console.log(resultJson);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: You've added Access-Control **response** headers to the **request** and you seem to have shared with us the details of a GET request when the error message says it is the preflight OPTIONS request which is failing. You don't seem to have shared any of the server side code which generates the response either.

Comment: Hi Quentin, here is the server response "Reload the page to get source for: https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/user". In restclient I can get the right json response that I need with no errors.